# ReferenceError: require is not defined (Paynow)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, payment-gateway, console.log

I understand a similar question has been asked before. I am trying to import a payment gateway module (paynow/nodeJS) into a web application. Browser console is displaying

> "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

at line

```
const { Paynow } = require("paynow");
```

What is that I could be doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a module system registered?

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely causes of this:

1. You are trying to run the JS in a browser instead of in Node.js
2. You have Node.js configured to use ES6 modules instead of CommonJS modules

If the former, run the code designed to be run in Node.js in Node.js.

If the latter, either use `import` instead or configure the system to use CommonJS modules (don't use the `.mjs` file extension and don't use [package.json's `type` field](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field).